# como acessar o jbutton que está na outra classe?

Tags: java, netbeans

tenho o jbutton na classe principal, dai coloquei ele como public para poder acessar de outra classe.
mas está sem fazer o correto

```
public class piscarbt{

 tela t = new tela();
public void piscar(){

    t.jButton1.setBackground(Color.white);

}


}
```

[image: esse a foto do código fonte do botão, ele está no netbeans]

fiz esse código e a cor do jbutton não altera, lembrando que na classe principal ele está`public javax.swing.JButton jButton1;`

não sei o qeu fazer pois ele já está como publico

Comment: Não é muito fácil de fazer, mas não é impossivel de aprender. Veja http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115672/change-jbutton-gradient-color-but-only-for-one-button-not-all?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Faz um get do botão na classe principal:

```
public JButton getBotao() {
return seuBotao;
}
```

Na outra classe instância a a principal:

```
ClassePrincipal controle = new ClassePrincipal():
```

E seu código irá ficar assim:

```
JButton botao = controle.getBotao();
t.botao.setBackground(Color.white);
```

Tenta ai e da um feedback

Comment: Só isso não vai resolver, dependendo do LAF que estiver sendo aplicado. Pois quem colore o button é o UIManager, e esse método por si só não altera o bakcground.

Comment: o que eu devo fazer diego

Comment: @DiogoCipriano eu postei um link com um exemplo, talvez se você adaptar, atenda.

Comment: consegui mudar a cor dele porém tem um  porém eu mando ele mudar duas vezes usando thread e ele só muda a ultima sempre

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar o botão como estático:

`Private Static JButton btnBotão;`

E criar um método estatico pra chamar esse botão:

`public static JButton getButton(){
     return btnBotao;
}`

tudo isso na classe principal.

Na classe que vc for chamar esse botão pode chamar pelo método estatico:

`Principal.getButton().addActionListener()` .... enfim, implementa como desejar